# Remove from JMenuItem

Tags: java, swing, jpopupmenu, jmenu

OK so I finally got the JListMenu thing down with thanks to you guys. However, now I'm trying to make it so SPECIFIC items have SPECIFIC commands. So, like Item 1 won't have the ability to right-click Cancel but Items 2, Item 3, and Item 4 can. See where I'm going?

So here's my code so far:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;

public class inv extends JApplet implements MouseListener
{
    public JList listbox;
    public JPopupMenu popup;
    public JMenuItem item;

    public void init()
    {
        ActionListener menuListener = new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
            {
                String invAction = event.getActionCommand();


                int itemSelect = listbox.getSelectedIndex();
                Object actItem = listbox.getModel().getElementAt(itemSelect);

                System.out.println("Popup menu item [" + invAction + "] [ " + actItem + " ] was pressed.");
            }
        };

        popup = new JPopupMenu();

        popup.add(item = new JMenuItem("Use"));
        item.addActionListener(menuListener);

        popup.add(item = new JMenuItem("Drop"));
        item.addActionListener(menuListener);

        popup.add(item = new JMenuItem("Cancel"));
        item.addActionListener(menuListener);



        String listData[] =
        {
            "Item 1","Item 2","Item 3","Item 4"
        };

        listbox = new JList( listData );
        listbox.addMouseListener( new MouseAdapter()
        {
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
            {
                if ( SwingUtilities.isRightMouseButton(e) )
                {
                    System.out.println("Row: " + getRow(e.getPoint()));
                    listbox.setSelectedIndex(getRow(e.getPoint()));
                }
            }
        }
        );

        listbox.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        add(listbox);
        listbox.setVisible(true);
        listbox.setFocusable(false);


        listbox.addMouseListener(new MousePopupListener());
    }

    class MousePopupListener extends MouseAdapter
    {
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
        {
            checkPopup(e);
        }

        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
        {
            checkPopup(e);
        }

        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e)
        {
            checkPopup(e);
        }

        private void checkPopup(MouseEvent e)
        {
            if (e.isPopupTrigger())
            {

                int itemSelectx = listbox.getSelectedIndex();
                Object actItemx = listbox.getModel().getElementAt(itemSelectx);
                System.out.println("You pressed on " + actItemx);

                popup.show(inv.this, e.getX(), e.getY());
                popup.revalidate();
            }
        }
    }

    private int getRow(Point point)
    {
        return listbox.locationToIndex(point);
    }

    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e)
    {
    }

    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e)
    {
    }

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
    {
    }

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
    {
    }

    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e)
    {
    }
}
```

and, it works! I mean, right-click and you'll see the option you selected on which item list. However there IS a small warning label on the menu-item upon right-click. Weird.

Anwways, right below `System.out.println("You pressed on " + actItemx);` I tried adding this:

```
        if (actItemx == "Item 1") {
            System.out.println("Removed cancel for " + actItemx);
            popup.remove(2); // So upon right-click on Item 1, you won't see "Cancel" menu.
        }
```

and it seemed to work (but it's not done yet because then I gotta RE-add it, heh). However, when I right-clicked, the Cancel was gone. Like expected. Woo! But then I right-clicked it again and I got this error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-1" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: index
 greater than the number of items.
        at javax.swing.JPopupMenu.remove(JPopupMenu.java:412)
        at inv$MousePopupListener.checkPopup(inv.java:102)
        at inv$MousePopupListener.mouseReleased(inv.java:88)
        at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:2
73)
        at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6267)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3267)
        at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6032)
        at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2041)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4630)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2099)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4460)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4577
)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4238)

        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4168)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2085)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4460)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:599)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThre
ad.java:269)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.
java:184)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThre
ad.java:174)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)

        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)

        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
```

Ah, well -- back to the drawing board. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: well, your program is working as expected. after removing the cancel meu item, if you click "item 1" , your code is trying to remove again popup menu item with index 2.. It gives exception as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
popup.remove(2);
```

with

```
popup.remove(itemSelectx);
```

Comment: It works but... now... it will remove ALL of the menu items... eventually having no more menu items. :(

Comment: Maybe there's a way that I can ADD instead of remove menu items... you know?